# Delphi 7 - Draw circle with transparent core using canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-7

I'm trying to draw a simple circle using `Delphi 7` and `Canvas`, and I'm doubt if what I want to do is possible.

As the following image, I want to draw a circle without a core/center:

[image: Core transparent]
[image: Pie]

With Jerry Dodge suggestion:

[image]

- I don't need of the red part, only the blue part.

Code used:

```
Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
Canvas.Pen.Color := clGreen;
Canvas.Pen.Width := 20;
Canvas.Pie(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4);
```

---

Old information:

The background image is a simple `TImage` component and I draw the circle using this command:

```
Canvas.Brush.Color := clgreen;
Canvas.Pie(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4);
```

---

Is it possible?

---

**Solved after Tom Brunberg and Jerry Dodge help!**

**Result:**

[image: tom]

---

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Draw it to a separate canvas first, most commonly a `TBitmap`, then draw that bitmap to the final canvas with transparency.

Comment: Also, why use `Pie` for this task? Why not `Ellipse`?

Comment: Or maybe you could use a high pen width, for example `Canvas.Pen.Width := 100;` and then no fill `Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;` That will probably be much easier, as well as better performing.

Comment: Thank you for your help @JerryDodge, I'm using `Pie` because I need to develop programatically a "circular slider"  (like new image of the body of the question) and with a transparency in center. Is it clear?

Comment: My answer should still work perfectly. Just replace the `Ellipse` call with your `Pie` call instead.

Comment: @JerryDodge You are helping me a lot... I added a new image containing the result using your answer, but... Do you know if possible to do it without `red` marks of the image attached in the question?

Comment: If you want an arc instead of pie, use the Arc() function

Comment: Hmm, yeah I can see your dilemma. You can use `Arc` instead. Added to my answer below.

Comment: Wow!!! Thank yoou very much!! JerryDodge and Tom Brunberg it works like a charm!

Comment: @TomBrunberg answer my question to give you +1

Comment: Oh, thanks but @Jerry 's answer already covers the Arc().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of a few ways to do this, but the easiest way is to use a large pen width with no fill. For example...

```
Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
Canvas.Pen.Color := clGreen;
Canvas.Pen.Width := 50;
Canvas.Pie(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4);
```

In your case however, `Pie` is not the proper approach, because it will also leave lines in the middle. You will have to use `Arc` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is the routine:

```
procedure SetCircle(centerRadius,CenterAngle:real; r:integer);
{Draw a circle centered at CenterRadius, CenterAngle from image center,
 radius of circle drawn is r}
var x,y:integer;
begin
  with cfrm.canvas do begin
   x:=trunc(midx+CenterRadius*cos(CenterAngle));
    y:=trunc(midy+CenterRadius*sin(CenterAngle));
    ellipse(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r);
    cfrm.canvas.brush.color:=clyellow;
  end;
end;
```